# How to exec code after res.send() in express server at Firebase cloudFunctions

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, response, connection-close

I'm building an express server using the cloud functions, but I facing a problem with `res.send()`.
In a common express server I can exec some code after `res.send()` but at my express server using the Firebase cloudFunctions `res.send()` closes my connection and I can't exec anything after that.

Here is what I need to do:
In my server I have an endpoint to receive some data from Slack api dialog, and after that Slack Api is waiting for a empty response `res.send()`, so I need to send it.
But I also need to save that data in my DB, and send a message in slack to my user *"Your post was saved!"*
So what my endpoint does:

```
async function myEndpoint(req, res) {
    await savePayload(req.payload);
    await sendUserMessage(req.payload);
    res.send('');
}
```

But sometimes `res.send()` takes to long to start running and I get an error on slack, so I would like to do something like:

```
async function myEndpoint(req, res) {
    res.send('');
    await savePayload(req.payload);
    await sendUserMessage(req.payload);
}
```

But as I said, after `res.send('')` my connection is closed and the next lines doesn't run. Do you know how can I work around that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP functions immediately terminate execution once the response is completed -- this is fundamental architecture for Cloud Functions, so there is no way around it. You will need to either:

1. Optimize your code paths such that the empty response is always sent under the deadline, or
2. Trigger a background function execution that will do the work asynchronously, then respond. This could be done by e.g. writing to Cloud Firestore or sending a Pub/Sub message

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael, I was thinking, it's possible to have a second endpoint to do that work for me ? Something like, receive the slack dialog data, call another endpoint to do everything I need (but without waiting for the response) and then call `res.send()` ?

Comment: That might work, the only problem would be you'd have to wait long enough to make sure the second request has actually started processing before `res.send()` (network is clamped in addition to CPU etc. as soon as the response is sent). You might be able to do this reliably with a timeout, but using Pub/Sub or another background function will be a more surefire reliable solution.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I want to write to PubSub after calling `res.send()`. Do i have to wait for the PubSub message to be succesfully sent (waiting for the promise to resolve), before calling `res.send()`?

Comment: Yes, you need to wait for the PubSub message to be sent before calling `res.send()` -- you can't count on *anything* executing for sure after the response has ended.